# Is there a way to predict (or measure) how long it will take to execute a single line of code?

Tags: performance, optimization, language-agnostic, computer-science

My question is this:

***Given a single line of isolated code (ie., does not parse, read/write to file on HDD, not a subroutine, etc.), is it possible to predict or measure with any degree of accuracy and/or consistency how long the code will take to execute on a given system?***

For example, say I have the following code (not in any specific language, just a generalization):

```
1 |  If x = 1 then
2 |    x = x + 1
3 |  End If
```

how long would it take to execute line 2?

I am *not* looking for numbers here; I am just wondering if such a thing is possible or practical.

Thanks!

Update:

Now I am looking for some numbers... If I were to execute a simple `For` loop that simply sleeps 1 second per iteration, after 60 (actual) minutes, how far off would it be? In other words, can the time taken to evaluate a line of isolated code be considered negligible (assuming no errors or interrupts)?

Comment: If you're looking for numbers, don't look here.  Set up an experiment and gather some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at documentation such as [this](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) you will find how many clock cycles the fundamental operations take on a CPU, and how long those clock cycles are.  Translating those numbers into the time taken to perform `x = x+1` in your program is an imprecise science, but you'll get some kind of clue by examining the assembly code listing that your compiler produces.

The science becomes less and less precise as you move from simple arithmetic statements towards large programs and you start hitting all sorts of issues arising from the complexity of modern CPUs and modern operating systems and memory hierarchies and all the rest.

Comment: Hmm I doubt that this works to any degree on modern CPUs. Just the most obvious example: 100 instructions that all depend on each other will be much slower than 300 instructions that are independent (although intel is getting better and better on prediction, so writing the first code could be not that easy anymore).

Comment: +1 I've watched academics lamenting the lack of predictability about how long things take, but the whole point of pipelining and cacheing is to be opportunistic and save cycles when the unpredictable chance arises, so the price paid for performance is it becomes a stochastic game.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to run it a billion times, see how much time it took, and then divide by one billion. This should remove the problems with clock accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be interested in learning about [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  Using Big O, you you can figure out how to write the most efficient algorithms regardless of the speed of the machine on which it is running.

Most computers will usually have some processes, services or other "jobs" running in the background and consuming resources at different times for various reasons... which will tend to make it hard to predict exact execution times.  However if you could break down the above code into assembly language and calculate the number of bits, registers and clock ticks that are used at the machine level, I would assume that it would be possible to get an accurate estimation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a resounding no. For example consider what would happen if an interrupt was raised during the addition: the next instruction would be executed *after* the interrupt has been serviced, therefore giving the impression that the addition took an awful lot of time.

If we're talking about an ISR-disabled condition, then the answer is "it depends". For example, consider that a branch misprediction on the `if` would probably slow down the execution a lot. The same could be said about multicore CPUs (often some of the ALUs are shared between cores, so activity on a core could affect the performance of operations on other cores).

If we're talking about an ISR-disabled condition on a CPU with a single core and a single-stage pipeline then I guess you should be pretty much able to predict how long it takes. Problem is, you'd be probably working on a microcontroller (and an old one, at that). :)

update: on second thought, even in the last case you probably wouldn't be able to predict it exactly: in fact some operations are data-dependant (the canonical example being floating point operations on denormal numbers).

Answer (score 0):

A way you can figure it out is writing that line of code 1000 times and then time how long it takes to run that code and then dividing the time by 1000, to get a more acurate time you can run that test 10 times and see the average time you got out of all those tests.